# ctor initializer list with std::thread and this

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, this, initializer-list

I have read some stuff about 'this' being unsafe in the initializer list of the constructor. I have a rather large app and I traced some undefined behavior to using std::thread with 'this' in the initializer list of a constructor. When I moved the std::thread construction out of the initializer list and into the constructor the app works without errors.

I tried to reproduce the problem with an example but it runs perfectly.
Can anybody explain why the combo of std::thread, 'this' and initializer list might give undefined behavior. I think it has to do with 'this' not being fully initialized when you call the std::thread constructor but that is just guessing.

I would like to be able to reproduce the problem.
Tried with g++4.9.2 and g++5.4 on ubuntu 16.04.
I compiled with -g and -O0 to debug. Also tried with -O2 and -O3.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

//g++ -std=c++11 -g -O0 -pthread init_thread.cpp -o init_thread

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
 |   TEMPLATE FUNCTIONS
 + ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#if __cplusplus < 201402L
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
#endif


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- +
 |   CLASSES
 + ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
class X
{
public:
    X() = delete;

    X(int x) : x_(x)
    {
        t_ = std::thread(&X::foo, this);
        printf("Ctor X\n");
    }

    ~X()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxState_);
            state_ = State::terminated;
        }
        cv_.notify_one();
        if (t_.joinable())
        {
            t_.join();
        }
        printf("Dtor X\n");
    }

private:
    enum class State
    {
        suspended,
        running,
        terminated
    };

    int x_;
    mutable std::mutex mtxState_;
    State state_ { State::running };
    mutable std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::thread t_;

    void foo()
    {
        while (state_ != State::terminated)
        {
            switch (state_)
            {
                case State::suspended:
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtxState_);
                        cv_.wait(lck, [this] { return state_ != State::suspended; });
                    }
                    break;
                case State::running:
                    {
                        printf("do something X...\n");
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
};


class I
{
public:
    I() = delete;
    I(int i) {};
};


class A : I
{
public:
    A() = delete;

    A(int a) : I(a), a_(a), x_obj_with_thread_(make_unique<X>(15)), t_(std::thread(&A::foo, this))
    {
        printf("Ctor A\n");
    }

    ~A()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxState_);
            state_ = State::terminated;
        }
        cv_.notify_one();
        if (t_.joinable())
        {
            t_.join();
        }
        printf("Dtor A\n");
    }

private:
    enum class State
    {
        suspended,
        terminated
    };

    int a_;
    mutable std::mutex mtxState_;
    State state_ { State::suspended };
    mutable std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::thread t_;
    std::unique_ptr<X> x_obj_with_thread_;

    void foo()
    {
        while (state_ != State::terminated)
        {
            switch (state_)
            {
                case State::suspended:
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtxState_);
                        cv_.wait(lck, [this] { return state_ != State::suspended; });
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("do something A...\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
};

class B : I
{
public:

    B() = delete;

    B(int b) : I(b), b_(b), x_obj_with_thread_(make_unique<X>(15))
    {
        t_ = std::thread(&B::bar, this);
        printf("Ctor B\n");
    }

    ~B()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxState_);
            state_ = State::terminated;
        }
        cv_.notify_one();
        if (t_.joinable())
        {
            t_.join();
        }
        printf("Dtor B\n");
    }

private:
    enum class State
    {
        suspended,
        terminated
    };

    int b_;
    mutable std::mutex mtxState_;
    State state_ { State::suspended };
    mutable std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::thread t_;
    std::unique_ptr<X> x_obj_with_thread_;

    void bar()
    {
        while (state_ != State::terminated)
        {
            switch (state_)
            {
                case State::suspended:
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtxState_);
                        cv_.wait(lck, [this] { return state_ != State::suspended; });
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("do something B...\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
};


void testA()
{
    for (int i=0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        printf("A iteration %i\n", i);
        A a(15);
    }
}

void testB()
{
    for (int i=0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        printf("B iteration %i\n", i);
        B b(15);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::thread a(testA);
    std::thread b(testB);
    a.join();
    b.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the standard, using a member function in the initializer list can result in undefined behavior:

> Member functions (including virtual member functions) can be called
>   from member initializers, but the behavior is undefined if not all
>   direct bases are initialized at that point.

Direct base classes are initialized in left to right order.

In your example however, the problem is that the initialization of the object itself (this) is not finished, and it is already passed to the thread, captured by the condition variable and referenced.

The following code has crashed once because the mutex was not initialized, but I can't get it to reproduce consistently:

```
class withthread
{
public:

    withthread(): b(false),t(std::thread(&withthread::func,this))

    {

    }
    ~withthread()
    {
        t.join();
    }
    void func()
    {
        int d=5;
        while ( --d  ) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
            v.wait(l,[this]() {this->b=true;return b;});
            cout << 2 << endl;
        }
    }
    std::thread t;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable v;
    bool b;
};

int main(){
    withthread w1 ;
    withthread *w ;
    w = new withthread();
    delete w;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your interpretation of the quote you cite is radically different from what the quote says. Calling member functions from the member-init-list isn't undefined behaviour. You just need to be careful that the things you're calling and using have actually been initialized.

Comment: Thanks I will edit so it expresses better what you mentioned

Comment: Apparently the member variables where in the right order (not like in the example). But there are member variables that are used in the thread that are initialized in the class after those of the initializer list. So if i put these first is it safe to call the member funtion in initializer list?

Comment: Testing with the changed order seems to have fixed the undefined behavior. Not sure what to put as answer cause it was the combination of the 2 that made me figure out the problem

Answer (score 4):

Inside the constructor member-init-list (which is the formal name of the stuff between the prototype (X(int x)) and the body ({…}) in the constructor definition), this is usable up to the point that the data members you access have been initialized. The order of initialization of data members is defined not by their order in the member-init-list, but their order in the class definition (e.g. Clang warns if the order in the former does not match that in the latter).

So in principle, as long as the thread is the last class member, this is completely usable (barring any extra initialization performed in the constructor body, which is executed after the member-init-list is run through.

Looking at your code for class A, it seems you have run into the initialization order error I described: your unique_per member is defined after the thread, but you mistakenly assume putting the unique_ptr first in the member-init-list will change the order of their initialization. It doesn't, and you might be running into issues related to that. In B, the thread is first default initialized: leaving it out of the member-init-list does not mean it isn't first default-initialized! Then in the constructor body, you actually start a thread running a function.